# Hibernate Projection returning wrong List of object types?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to pull all of mapped entities using a group by Projection to return a list of the mapped objects as there are many entries but I am only interested in if there is an entry.

```
public <T> List<T> queryWithGroupBy(Class<T> clazz, String property){
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(clazz);
    crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty(property), property));
    List<T> results = crit.list();
    return results;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="MAPPED_MARK")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.docShell", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DSHELL_ID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.docBookmark", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DMARK_ID"))
})
public class MappedDocBookmark implements Serializable{...}
```

The Service methods are

```
public List<MappedDocBookmark> listOfGroupByMappedBookmarks() {
    List<MappedDocBookmark> list = dbDAO.queryWithGroupBy(MappedDocBookmark.class, "pk.docBookmark");       
    return list;
}

public List<DocBookmark> getListOfUnMappedBookmarks() {
    List<DocBookmark> list = getListOfDocBookmarks();//get all listed
    List<MappedDocBookmark> mappedDocBookmarks = listOfGroupByMappedBookmarks();//get mapped
    for (MappedDocBookmark mapped : mappedDocBookmarks){//filter
        if (list.contains(mapped.getDocBookmark())){
            list.remove(mapped.getDocBookmark());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

I have inserted a test record in the database and here are My Tests:

The first one passes, but shouldn't in my mind.

```
    @Test
    public void loadGroupedMappedDocBookmarRecords(){
        List<MappedDocBookmark> alist = docBookmarkService.listOfGroupByMappedBookmarks();
        assertNotNull  (alist);
        assert (!alist.isEmpty() && alist.size()>0);
        DocBookmark db =  = docBookmarkService.getDocBookmarkById(1L);          
        assert (alist.get(0).equals(db) );
    }
```

The second one does not pass and gets a ClassCastException at the `(MappedDocBookmark mapped : mappedDocBookmarks){//filter` line.  When I debug the test, it appears that a `List<DocBookmark>` was returned rather than `List<MappedDocBookmark>`

```
    @Test
    public void loadOrphanedDocBookmarRecords(){
        List<DocBookmark> alist = docBookmarkService.getListOfUnMappedBookmarks();
        assertNotNull  (alist);
        assert (!alist.isEmpty() && alist.size()>0);
        DocBookmark db = null;
        try {
            db = docBookmarkService.getDocBookmarkById(1L);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            assert (false);
        }
        assert (!alist.contains(db) );
    }
```

Please Advise and Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve with `queryWithGroupBy`. Applying a projection list results in a list of object arrays and applying `group by` returns only the grouped column(s). But you expect a list of your entities.

Comment: I am trying to get a list of MappedBookmark when ultimately the  query should look like SELECT * FROM mapped_mark group by DMARK_ID;

Comment: That's not a valid SQL query. What result do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[zeroflagL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151351/zeroflagl),  your comment got me to think about what to do as I misinterpreted what hibernate was doing with the group projection and the group by SQL itself. I can return the list of the DocBookmark rather than the `MappedDocBookmark`. This is a solution but begs to now know that the `List<Object>` is a `List<DocBookmark>`

```
public <T> List<Object> queryWithGroupBy(Class<T> clazz, String property){
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(clazz);
    crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty(property), property));
    return crit.list(); 
}
```